# $util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

How do you use this?

From here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html

I am trying to basically do this:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Scan",
    "filter" : {
      $util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression({
        PartitionKey:{
            begins_with:"Model"
        }
      }),
    }
}
```

That isn't working. How exactly do you fit this command into a resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: If you have a type

```
type Post { id: ID! title String! }
```

then *util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression* would expect the value you provide to look like this:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Scan",
    "filter" : $util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression(
      {
        id: {
          beginsWith:"Model"
        }
      }
   )
}
```

The *$util.transform* utility functions were designed to work with a new project called the GraphQL Transform that was just released as part of AWS Amplify. The gist is that a set of client tools takes a simplified input schema annotated with GraphQL directives and passes it through a series of "transformers" that "transform" it into a fully descriptive CloudFormation document (and other output formats in the future). That CF doc fully implements the application defined by the schema and set of transformers (which you can write yourself for custom workflows).

You can read more about the project here (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/master/graphql-transform-tutorial.md).

And about how to write your own transformers here (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/master/how-to-write-a-transformer.md)

Comment: What if I just want it to be 'equal to' or 'not equal to' something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra brackets. And the correct syntax is "beginsWith".
So your example should look like this:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Scan",
    "filter" : $util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression({
        PartitionKey:{
            beginsWith:"Model"
        }
      })
}
```

For other comparisons use:

ne: Not equals
  eq: Equals
  le: Lower or equal
  lt: Lower than
  ge: Greater or equal
  gt: Greater than
  contains: Contains (For array or string)
  notContains: Not contains (Same, array or string) 
  between: Between (Needs two arguments)
  beginsWith: Begins with